# why rectangle border is not the same size in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason I get an uneven border for my rectangle. If i use an even value for the width then the border looks like one part of a thicker then the other. If I use an odd value for width then the border looks correct. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys

SCREEN_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600
SCREEN_COLOR = pygame.Color("white")

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
FRAME_RATE = 30

class Vehicle(object):
  INNER_COLOR = (0, 0, 0, 127)
  RIM_COLOR = pygame.Color("black")
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

    surface = pygame.Surface((40, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA, 32)
    surface = surface.convert_alpha()

    self.rect = surface.get_rect()

    pygame.draw.rect(
        surface,
        self.INNER_COLOR,
        self.rect,
    )

    pygame.draw.rect(
        surface,
        self.RIM_COLOR,
        self.rect,
        4
    )

    self.surface = surface

  def display(self):
    SCREEN.blit(self.surface, (self.x - 20, self.y - 40))

def main():
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  v = Vehicle(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)

  while True:
    clock.tick(FRAME_RATE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

    SCREEN.fill(SCREEN_COLOR)

    v.display()

    pygame.display.flip()

if '__main__' == __name__:
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

self.rect = surface.get_rect()

is the bad line. The width creates a rectangle with the given width, with the border centered on the given rectangle. Because you are creating a rectangle that exactly fills the target surface, half of the rectangle is off the canvas.

Replacing it with

self.rect = (4, 4, 30, 70)

gives me a properly-sized border.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because pygame centres the border you create on the inside edge of the surface. This looks something like the following:

```
Imagine #### is the border
Now centre it on this:
  |
You cant do it. You either get:
 #|##
Or you get:
##|#
```

This is the sole reason it doesn't work.
I took two screenshots after changing the draw rect size to 30 by 70 and then drew on where the draw rect said the border was. (I changed the colours to make them more obvious)
[image][image]

The first is border size 4 and the second, border size 5. Zoom into them for a bit more detail.
So in a way it is a problem with your code but it shouldn't be too hard to fix. I'll leave that for you as a challenge, but if you struggle, just tell me and I'll edit this post and add and example.